# Will Eating Dark chocloate help to reduce fat?

Tags: bellyfat

I have belly fat and I want to reduce it. So I am in dilemma whether eating Dark Chocolate will help or not.

Because many posts on google suggested it will help to reduce fat, but it contains sugar content. So will it increase fat much more ?

Comment: Not all dark chocolate contains sugar.  If you look for chocolate in the baking aisle, you can find bars that are labeled by their cocoa percentage.  100% cocoa is 0% sugar notwithstanding trace or negligible amounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to lose weight just eat less. Find out how many calories you need to maintain your current weight and just eat 250-500 calories less than that. If your main goal is to lose weight it doesn't really matter what you eat, but eating healthy is always better.

As for dark chocolate I believe it suppresses your appetite, due to the amount of fibre it contains. So it basically helps you stay in a caloric deficit.